# How to handle dynamic routes, non existing pages and no existing data from GraphQL request in Astro project

Tags: javascript, graphql, http-status-code-404, astrojs

How do I solve the following issue in my [Astro](https://astro.build) project:

I can request the page content `data` for various pages from my GraphQL endpoint. I am using [Apollo Client](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/) for this.

Using the following query as an example:

```
query Page($target: String!) {
  page(target: $target) {
    id
    type
    content {
      ...on PageOne {
        id
        title
        field
      }
      ...on PageTwo {
        id
        title
        anotherField
      }
      ...on PageThree {
        id
        title
        description
      }
    }
  }
}

In Astro I created dynamic routes:

// pages/[...url].astro
---
import { Page } from '../components/page';

const url = `/${Astro.params.url}`;
---
<Page url={url} />
```

**Note:** I like to have a separate Astro component for the  logic and mapping:

```
// Page.astro
---
const { url } = Astro.props;

const { data, loading } = await client.query({
  query: GET_PAGE,
  variables: {
    target: url,
  },
  errorPolicy: 'all',
});


const Map = {
  "PageOne": PageOneComponent,
  "PageTwo": PageTwoComponent,
};

const Component = Map[data.page?.type]
---

<Component content={content} />
```

This all works fine. When hitting a certain `target` url (existing in the backend) I can request the `data` and pass it via a prop to the individual corresponding Astro components (PageOneComponent, PageTwoComponent etc).

The problem starts when trying a non existing page. Or trying a page with a page type which exist in the backend but I am not querying the content yet, since I am gradually building and adding the pages.

On a non existing page `data.page?.type` is `undefined`. How do I handle this in a clean way?

I can do something like this in `[...url].astro`:

```
if (data.page?.type in Map === false) {
 return new Response(null, {
 status: 404,
 statusText: 'Not found',
 });
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot do above inside `Page.astro` then I get the [following error](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/errors/response-sent-error/):

> ResponseSentError: The response has already been sent to the browser
> and cannot be altered.

1. Do I have to make then another GraphQL query inside `[...url].astro` to solve this issue?
2. And what about the other case (existing page without content)?
3. Just a non existing page which should return a 404 page.

I can simply move everything to `[...url].astro` but then that file becomes very crowded. I like to extract things to its own components and folders.

Comment: Why not just look at the `error` returned from `client.query` and navigate to the 404 page?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I can't do that inside `Page.astro`. When I try e.g. `if (error) {
  return new Response(null, {
    status: 404,
    statusText: 'Not found',
  });
}`, then I get an Astro error about the `<Component />`:
`Unable to render Component because it is undefined!
Did you forget to import the component or is it possible there is a typo? `? So I guess I can't avoid it to move the `client.query` to `[...url].astro`? And how would you 'navigate' to the 404 page, what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be 2 ways of handling this:

1. *redirect* the user to your 404 page with `Astro.redirect('/404')` or similar. On the plus side the user gets whatever look and functionality you have built in your 404 page. On the downside the URL will switch so they won't see what URL is 404.
2. Render a *not found* component.

In either case it is better to trigger this from the GraphQL `error` state rather than looking inside the `data` object.

Comment: The strange thing is. The `error` state is always `undefined`? Perhaps this is due to the use of Apollo Client inside Astro? Apollo Client is more for React usage. Do I maybe have to switch to TanStack Query?

Comment: Regarding 1). When I use `if (!(data.page?.type in Map)) {
 return new Response(null, {
 status: 404,
 statusText: 'Not found',
 });
}` it will show the custom Astro 404 page and you will still see the URL! This works fine. Why should you use`Astro.redirect('/404')` instead?

Comment: 1. It sounds like your server is not returning an error when it should - you're probably just returning `undefined` for your unimplemented routes. 2. You said that if you returned a new response you would get an error.

Comment: Ok. And why is it better to trigger this from the GraphQL `error` instead of the `data` object?

Comment: Why treat the values of *data* as error conditions when you have the ability to throw actual errors?

Comment: Clear thanks. When I try it with a non existing url in the GraphQL sandbox I get: `"errors": [
    {
      "message": "404: Not Found",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 1,
          "column": 41
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "page"
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "code": "INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR",
        "response": {
          "url": // etc.........`
Does this mean my server is returning `errors` array but not the `error` state?

Comment: GraphQL errors are returned as an array. What you are seeing is exactly what is expected.